# Android listview with checkbox and Radio Button

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-listview

here i used the listview with radio button and checkbox , i want my radiobutton to get checked only when the corresponding checkbox is selected and even i want those checked references so that i can put some conditions according to my requirement, thanks in advance.

Is there any better way than using listview ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any better way than using listview ?

Yes.

**CheckBoxes** are used when you want the user to select more than one option.

**RadioButtons** are used when you want the user to select ***one*** option out of many.

With that being said. You could either only use CheckBoxes or RadioButtons, using both together doesn't make sense, because both server a different purpose.

You could however use a [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) instead of a ListView.

Comment: in my case i want both checkbox and radiobuttons , so that i can select multiple rows using checkboxes and merge them in to main row in which radio button is selected

Comment: Well in that case, you could show a list of CheckBoxes, and when the user taps the merge button, you could show a popup with a RadioGroup to select where to merge it in.

Comment: that sounds good, but actually am new to android can you please say how to show popup with items on which checkboxes are selected

Comment: Here you can read this: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html